# Is it possible to access the Azure emulator from another computer on the same network?

Tags: debugging, iis, azure, emulation

I'm running Windows 7 (x64) with VS 2010 SP1 and the Windows Azure SDK 1.5. I'd like to be able to debug a web application on an iPhone connected to the same network to shorten debug cycles.

IIS is running on this machine and can see that a temporary site is being created when I debug the Azure project. Is there a way to add an additional binding to the IIS site so that I can connect from the the iPhone when the debug is started? I can manually add a binding once the debugger starts up but this is lost when I stop debugging.

Comment: you'd probably need to setup some sort of port forwading to map from an external IP to your localhost'ed azure instance

Comment: Port forwarding shouldn't be required since it is using IIS which can have multiple bindings. The question really relates to how it is configuring the original temporary site that is setup.

Comment: Perhaps this: http://localno.de/ might help? Still needs a manual step, though.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee That's not too bad, but I was hoping for something that gave me control over the IIS config that is being generated.

Comment: You might be able to do some trickery with IIS through WMI in the RoleStart.cs file... but I'd not trust that to stay the same when the emulator is updated...

Comment: @Liel my question was asked years before yours ;)

Comment: Hmmm... sorry for that... I removed the flag.  :) Anyway, Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 9):

This is a very old thread, but I came across it trying to do the same thing- after more searching I found this:  and it worked great for me (Using Passport to pass the traffic)

http://blog.sacaluta.com/2012/03/windows-azure-dev-fabric-access-it.html

Comment: after trying 4 different methods suggested in various threads, this is by far the simplest. Just download the PassPort exe, run it, it's pretty self explanatory and it works well on Win 8 with VS 2012

Comment: I can't get this to work for accessing the development cloud storage - any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

you can use port forwarding to do that.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=800 connectaddress=127.255.0.0 connectport=82 protocol=tcp
```

More info here: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/remotely-accessing-the-windows-azure-compute-emulator/

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution that kind of works.

I went to IIS manager and created a new website that points to the folder were I'm developing, on the port 8000.

Now I can access it through http://ip-of-server:8000, and also debug the application.

Hope it works for you also.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovery this solution http://blog.piyushthacker.com/?p=24

Works fine for me :)

In newer version (1.3 and higher) you may need to change file IISConfigurator.exe.config file like in this solution http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2011/01/06/changing-the-windows-azure-compute-emulator-ip-address.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use Fiddler to create a proxy server (tick options **Act as system proxy on startup**, **Monitor all connections** and **Allow remote computers to connect**), configure the remote browser to use the proxy server, and access my Azure website via http://ipv4.fiddler:81/  Technique from [here](http://encosia.com/using-an-iphone-with-the-visual-studio-development-server/).

Comment: +1. the benefit of this approach is to monitor packets between emulated server and clients.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this,
Look at [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314935/2126652),
which is based [on this post](http://blog.piyushthacker.com/?p=24)