# Windows Azure Compute Emulator Error

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator, autoproxy

I have Azure SDK 1.6, WIF, Nuget 1.5, Azure Mobile Toolkik, Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 sp1, Windows Phone SDK 7.1 and many other latest sdk.
I tried two sample, the Tweet your blob from azure toolkit for wp7, and the following very basic sample from channel 9: 
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Windows-Phone-Push-Notifications-and-Windows-Azure
I can reach the webrole, i see the phone app running but both sample fail when the try to communicate (in the first case trying to tweet, in the second trying to register to the pushnotification service, it seems like the emulator cannot reach the local endpoint on 127.0.0.1.
I repeated the same exactly steps on a collegue machine with the same configuration and everything works fine.

The only difference i noticed is that my deployment show the following log (Compute Emulator):

```
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2011-12-01T01:11:02.168Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     10352
[MonAgentHost] Error:     14592
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
```

Googling around i found only a topics regarding an issue with the azure sdk 1.3 which shouldn't prevent the application from running properly, but i installed sdk 1.6 (twice).

Any hints to find a solution or identify the problem will be appreciated, i checked everything i could, and i don't even known if the problem is related with the message.

Comment: Are you running a local proxy like e.g. Fiddler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Azure Emulator from Another Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778456/accessing-azure-emulator-from-another-device)

Answer (score 14):

You should compare you and your colleague's internet proxy settings (network settings).

For some reason, it's trying to detect which internet proxy to use for http://127.0.0.1 which it shouldn't - it's local address.

> WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed
>   ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384097(v=vs.85).aspx

Does it work if you disable auto detect proxy in your network settings?

Another possibility is that error in your log is a Red Herring - this blog post suggests those errors in the log are benign and don't make anything fail:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/20/winhttpgetproxyforurl-failed-error-winhttp-autodetection-failed-12180-error-message-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-log.aspx

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of this, you need to disable the “Automatically detect settings” option in the Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I fixed it by making sure that my port forwarding service ([PassPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/)) was not running prior to starting up the Azure emulator.

When I installed PassPort it installed a Windows service and set it to start automatically. I stopped the service, set it to only start manually, then restarted the Azure emulator. After that I was up and running again.

For some background, the reason I was even using PassPort in the first place was to do some IE8 testing of my Azure hosted web site using a Windows XP VM. I found the steps to set this up on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789030/is-it-possible-to-access-the-azure-emulator-from-another-computer-on-the-same-ne) which linked to [this blog](http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-remotely-access-windows). I can still use PassPort and my VM to test my site in IE8, I just have to make sure not to start the PassPort service until after the Azure emulator and web site are up and running.

Your problem may not be related specifically to a port forwarding service but rather some other service that may have stolen port 81 from the Azure emulator.